# Stop hackers when hosting php files

Tags: php, ajax, security

I am hosting a php file which echo's out information that I store in my mysql database and
I plan to distribute the name of the file in a proxy php file(for a cross domain ajax app) 
which will grab the text in xml format.

What do I have to watch out for so my server/database doesn't get hacked?
I turned off indexing (if you could download the php file, you would have my connection information).

I can't use htaccess to block anyone, because there will potentially be random servers accessing it. 
So what else is necessary/can i do besides setting permissions of the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're just spitting information from your database and not actually allowing changes to happen, then I don't really see a risk. Just make sure localhost is the only thing that can talk to your database.

Even if you had directory listings on, PHP runs on the web server level. The file would be processed if someone downloaded it, thus your connection information would not be in the file; only the processed information would. The only way to download a PHP file without it being processed is to change the file extension to .PHPS.

In other words, I think you'll be fine in your current configuration, just do your standard SQL injection checks.

Comment: Ahh duh, your right, it only spit out xml. I had already set up sql injection, but then allowing localhost only communication, and probably select privileges only I hadn't thought of. Thanks guys.

Answer (score 2):

You should be aware of SQL Injection vulnerabilities - perhaps allow access to the database from localhost only - this will help with a whole load of security issues. ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection )

Answer (score 1):

You need to watch out for SQL- and path- injection.

Answer (score 1):

I'd make sure the SQL user which it's using only has SELECT permissions, or the bare minimum permissions necessary.